# How to query in mongodb with nested json

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have this json file:

```
 {
  "id" : 100,
  "boolean": 1,
  "color": 2,
  "MYtable": [{"a":1, "b":2}],
  "number": 4,
  "string": 5
}
{
  "id" : 200,
  "boolean": 1,
  "color": 22,
  "MYtable": [{"a":10, "b":20,"c":30}],
  "number": 42,
  "string": 52
}
{
  "id" : 300,
  "boolean": 13,
  "color": 223,
  "MYtable": [],
  "number": 423,
  "string": 523
}
```

Using a mongodb query I would like to get only the elements that have MYtable of size 1 or larger. For example in the above json I would only get the elements with id 100 and 200.

MYcollection is my database's collection.

I tried this:

```
MYcollection.find({ "MYtable": {"$size": {"$gt" :1}}})
```

and also this:

```
MYcollection.find({"$where" : "this.MYtable.length > 1"})
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try this `MYcollection.find({ $expr: { $gt: [{$size: "$Mytable"}, 1] } })`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet  Thanks! But it still doesn't work correctly :/ If I write db.col.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : "$MYtable"},0]}}), it prints only the elements with ids 100 and 200 but if i put 1 or higher it returns nothing! I think the problem is that MYtable has its elements in this form [{dictionary_elements}] and not in this form: [dictionary_elements] but I dont know how to solve that

Comment: You should use `$gte` instead of `$gt` nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$expr` with `$size` to filter the documents

```
db.col.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : "$MYtable"},1]}})
```

try using `$expr`, below from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

> $expr is faster than $where because it does not execute JavaScript and
>   should be preferred where possible.

**EDIT -1**

you may need to change your document structure to store the array elements

the below works with you document structure by converting the array element at 0 to an array to compare the size

```
db.col.find({$expr:{$gt:[{$size:{$ifNull:[{"$objectToArray":{$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$MYtable",[]]},0]}},[]]}},1]}})
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't work correctly :/ If I write db.col.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : "$MYtable"},0]}}), it prints only the elements with ids 100 and 200 but if i put 1 or higher it returns nothing! I think the problem is that MYtable has its elements in this form [{dictionary_elements}] and not in this form: [dictionary_elements] but I dont know how to solve that

Comment: updated the answer, not so efficient but still works, you may need to change your document structure to store array elements

Answer (score 0):

There is a imho hacky but often seen way:

```
db.collection.find({'yourArrayField.1' : {$exists : true}}
```

I am not sure currently, if there can be undefined fields between existing ones, but it is a simple solution that might work for you.